# Валидация номера телефона на Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как указазать что если условия обработки номера в инпуте не буду выполнятся тогда сделаем его красным. Если всё хорошо зеленым

```
<input type="text" placeholder="+380" class="input-tel" v-model="phone"
       @keypress="onlyNumbers" maxlength=10 minlength=10 >
```

Вот стили

```
.notvalid {border: 1px solid red;}
.valid {border: 1px solid lightgreen;}
```

Метод обработки ввода только чисел (номера телефона)

```
onlyNumbers(event) {
        let keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;
         if (keyCode < 48 || keyCode > 57) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Кнопка отправки запроса (Работает тогда если условия выполняются)

```
<button @click="secondReg()" type="submit">Get code</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно лучше, но это один из вариантов решения проблемы

Сначала разберемся с классами `valid` и `novalid`

```
<input type="text"
  placeholder="+380"
  class="input-tel"
  :class="{'notvalid': failedValidation.phone, 'valid': failedValidation.phone===false}"
  v-model="phone"
  @input="onlyNumbers"
  maxlength="10"
  minlength="10">
```

Ивент keypress заменить на ивент input, в prop `:class` можно передать объект с классами, которые будут применены по условию

В данном случае: класс `notvalid` применяется, если `failedValidation.phone === true`, а класс `valid`, если `failedValidation.phone === false`

`data()` будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
data() {
  return {
    failedValidation: {
      phone: null
    },
    phone: ''
  }
}
```

Удобно использовать объект `failedValidation`, потому что можно проверять, входящие в него структуры, как бы отделяя их от остального кода

С учетом нового кода изменим и методы:

```
methods: {
  onlyNumbers() {
    this.failedValidation.phone = !/^[\d]{10}$/.test(this.phone) ? true : false;
  },

  secondReg(){
    if( !this.failedValidation.phone ){
      // если телефон удачно проверен
      alert('ok')
    }
    else {
      // если проверка не пройдена
      alert('error')
    }
  }
}
```

Метод `onlyNumbers()` проверяет по регулярному выражению значение input (т.к. v-model для input это переменная phonе, то проверяет её). Если значение не соответствует регулярному выражению, то `failedValidation.phone` становится true, иначе false

Метод `secondReg()` проверяет `failedValidation.phone` и производит дальнейшие действия в зависимости от значения true или false

[Рабочий пример](https://codepen.io/pogorelove/pen/wvWoqJz)

Comment: Да, круто, но как переделать если номер будет в формате +380334445522  ???

Comment: из <input> убрать minlength, maxlength сделать = 13 (что соответствует длине +380334445522), в методе onlyNumbers() заменить "!/^[\d]{10}$/" на "!^\+[\d]{12}$", это позволит проверять внесенное в <input> на то, соответствует ли оно "+DDDDDDDDDDDD", где D - число [0-9]

Comment: @babakov.roman678 как вариант - также можно подключить любой mask модуль для vue, например [этот](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask), и добавить к <input> соответствующий v-mask, затем проводить проверки (либо исходя из документации выбранного mask модуля, либо любым иным способом)

Comment: перекиньте пожалуйста на кодепен, у меня почему-то не заработало

Comment: @babakov.roman678 в комментарии неправильно указал, заменить "!/^[\d]{10}$/" на "!/^\+[\d]{12}$/" - вот так. codepen обновил также

Answer (score 0):

Во первых вам не нужен метод, он избыточен, по хорошему наборы правил валидации вынести в отдельный файл, а саму валидацию переложить в вычисляемые свойства:

```js
import validators from '~/validalors.js'

export default {
  data: () => ({
    phone: null,
  }),
  computed: {
    isInvalidPhone() {
      return !validators.validatePhone(this.phone);
    },
  },
};
```

Затем уже в шаблоне вы можете использовать это свойство:

```html
<template>
  <input
    v-model="phone"
    :class={ notvalid: isInvalidPhone }
    class="input-tel"
    type="text"
    placeholder="+380"
    maxlength="10"
    minlength="10"
  >
</template>
```

Соотвественно класс инпута по умолчанию можно сделать valid, а далее invalid будет обрабатываться реактивно. Ну и далее вы можете использовать это вычисляемое свойство в методе `secondReg`.